# NGRX - Are 2 Actions fired (reliant on each other) guaranteed to be handled sequentially?

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have 2 actions, A and B.

A gets fired after B in the immediate next line inside a service.

A has a Reducer to update an object in state.

B has an Effect, which reads from the part of state that A writes to.

Is B guaranteed to get the latest value in state which was updated by A?

I can't find any supporting documentation, but it seems as if this is apparent because it's running in a JS engine which is single-threaded. I'd like to also find out if creating an Effect to separately listen to A and call B afterwards isn't over-engineering this call.

Comment: You can have an effect for action A, which triggers the action B instead of triggering A and B one after another and hope for sequentiallity

Comment: I thought of this too, the same thing would occur if I call them sequentially in code as mentioned in my 2nd line. That 'hope for sequentiality is exactly what I want to clarify @OctavianMărculescu